# Annihalator which is maximal among all other proper annihalators is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

The following is an exercise in Vakils notes on algebraic geometry and I came up with a really weird result and wanted to verify that it was correct.

> If $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ a nonzero $R-$module let $\text{Ann}(m)$ where $m \in M$ be maximal among all proper ideals which are annihalators of elements of $M$. Then $\text{Ann}(m)$ is a prime ideal.

$\text{Ann}(x)$ where $x \in M$ is defined as $\{r \in R: rx = 0\}$

Proof:

If $rs \in \text{Ann}(m)$ then $r \in \text{Ann}(sm)$. We can assume that $sm \neq 0$ because if $sm = 0,$ $s \in \text{Ann}(m)$ and we're done. This implies that $1 \notin \text{Ann}(sm)$ so $\text{Ann}(sm)$ is proper.

Clearly $\text{Ann}(m) \subset \text{Ann}(sm)$ so $\text{Ann}(m) = \text{Ann}(sm)$ because $\text{Ann}(m)$ is maximal. Thus $r \in \text{Ann}(m)$. But this argument is symmetric in $s$ and $r$ so $s \in \text{Ann}(m)$ aswell? This seems really weird... but the proof looks ok.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: In the proof, it seems you want to  prove that $r \in \operatorname{Ann}(m)$. But no, you intend to prove that $r \in \operatorname{Ann}(m)$ or $s \in \operatorname{Ann}(m)$. Why not write this explicitely?

Comment: Your argument is good, but it is not symmetric in $s$ and $r$ in the way that you suggest, as Olivier points out. You start by saying suppose $rs \in Ann(m)$, and then proceed to show that if $s$ is NOT in $Ann(m)$, then $r$ is in $Ann(m)$. It's true, then, that if you started instead by supposing that $r$ is not in $Ann(m)$, then $s$ must be in $Ann(m)$, but you can't run this argument once you've concluded $r \in Ann(m)$.

Comment: THAT makes sense, thank you @AlexWertheim If you write that as an answer I can accept it if you want the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit : this was wrong** You write "Clearly $\text{Ann}(m) \subset \text{Ann}(sm)$", but this doesn't seem clear at all to me. I think this statement is wrong, and I'm trying to come up with a counterexample.

Nvm, we have $\text{Ann}(m) \subset \text{Ann}(sm)$ indeed, since (as shown by Alex Wertheim and Noel Lundström in the comments below) if $rm = 0$ then $rsm = srm = 0$.

**What you actualy prove :** Assume $rs \in \operatorname{Ann}(m)$. If $s \notin \operatorname{Ann}(m)$ then $r \in \operatorname{Ann}(m)$.

This is logically equivalent to 
$$rs \in \operatorname{Ann}(m) \Longrightarrow r \in \operatorname{Ann}(m) \textrm{ or } s \in \operatorname{Ann}(m)$$
Which is the definition of $\operatorname{Ann}(m)$ being prime.

Comment: I think it's fine, isn't it? If $rm = 0$, then $rsm = srm = s(rm) = 0$, since $R$ is assumed to be commutative.

Comment: The ring is commutative so if $fm = 0$ then $fsm = sfm = s*0 = 0$

Comment: Whoops I missed commutativity!